# Android: create CheckBox in activity.java

Tags: android, android-activity, checkbox

Hi i want to create dynamical number of checkboxes (it depends on the length of array "genre") in an Android app then i did:

```
CheckBox [] checkbox;
String [] genre={"party","sport","music","café","education"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    checkbox=new CheckBox[genre.length];
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);
    for(int i=0;i<genre.length;i++){
        CheckBox c=new CheckBox(this);
        c.setText(genre[i]);
        checkbox[i]=c;  
    }
     ArrayAdapter<CheckBox>adapter= new ArrayAdapter<CheckBox>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,checkbox);
     ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.genre_list);
     lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

but in the listview it shows numbers of the checkboxes in memory(I guess), why?

```
like : Android.wiget.CheckBox@44f03160
       Android.wiget.CheckBox@44f03d60
      ...
```

Comment: Please read this: http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/rkirchne/cs217/thompsod-proj/ArraysandVectors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd rather use the `android.R.simple_list_item_checked` item layout and enable multiple-choice on the list:

```
String [] genre={"party","sport","music","café","education"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, genre);
    ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.genre_list);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

This way you don't have to create the checkboxes manually by yourself

Comment: Thanks Fiddler
now it is clickable with mutilple choice, but it still wont show the string from string array, it still shows

Comment: Did you actually use the code I've put ? Because it works for me

Comment: above code for fine. But how I get the list of checked items from above code?

Answer (score 0):

Because of this line

```
 c.setText(genre[i]);
```

Comment: That's rather because the ArrayAdapter calls the `toString()` method of the Checkbox

Comment: Instead of that, use default layout of check list in array adapter i.e. R.layout.simple_list_item_checked. Or if you have some custom layout then make custom Adapter and custom list item, so that check box will be set according to the length of String array

Answer (score 0):

```
String [] genre={"party","sport","music","café","education"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkbox);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, genre);
    ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.genre_list);
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}



This looks like checkboxes.
```