# adding a checkboxpreference in java rather than xml android

Tags: android, xml, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am wondering if it is possible(and if so then how)to add a checkboxpreference for every number of firebase children I detect.  For example, if I call a query to firebase in order to get all of my users payment information, can I then make a checkboxpreference for the number of credit cards that the user has on file.

However, since I wont have a exact number of boxes(since it will be different for every user) needed I will have to add these checkboxes in java rather than in the xml code, how is this done? Thank You

Comment: You can Use recyclerview for that. or You can make CheckBok in java also. (Recycler view would be better) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474709/android-create-checkbox-in-activity-java

Comment: Although can I use a recyclerview even though it's in a preference activity?

Comment: You clearly did not google for add checkboxpreference dynamically.